# call to undefined function apache_request_headers Slim framework

Tags: php, apache, http, slim

I'm only posting this because none of the other posts have helped solve my problem. I'm using slim and advanced rest api app on chrome for testing. I've tried many suggestions on the web but nothing is working. I'm running php 5.5 on hostgator. I am getting the error when passing authorization header:

> call to undefined function apache_request_headers()

```
  <?php

require_once '../include/DbHandler.php';
require_once '../include/PassHash.php';
require '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();


// User id from db - Global Variable
$user_id = NULL;


function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route) {
    // Getting request headers
    $headers = apache_request_headers();
    $response = array();
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

    // Verifying Authorization Header
    if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
        $db = new DbHandler();

        // get the api key
        $api_key = $headers['Authorization'];
        // validating api key
        if (!$db->isValidApiKey($api_key)) {
            // api key is not present in users table
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Access Denied. Invalid Api key";
            echoRespnse(401, $response);
            $app->stop();
        } else {
            global $user_id;
            // get user primary key id
            $user_id = $db->getUserId($api_key);
        }
    } else {
        // api key is missing in header
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Api key is misssing";
        echoRespnse(400, $response); 
        //echoRespnse(400, $headers);

        $app->stop();
    }
}
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

Comment: Function apache-request-headers() if only available for Apache. Hostgrator is most likely using something else such as Nginx.

Comment: I get the same error on my local machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating, this seems to take care of the the header problem

```
   if (!function_exists('apache_request_headers')) { 


       function apache_request_headers() { 
            foreach($_SERVER as $key=>$value) { 
                if (substr($key,0,5)=="HTTP_") { 
                    $key=str_replace(" ","-",ucwords(strtolower(str_replace("_"," ",substr($key,5))))); 
                    $out[$key]=$value; 
                }else{ 
                    $out[$key]=$value; 
        } 
            } 
            return $out; 
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.4.0 and later supports apache_request_headers(). But there are other solutions like the code below which comes from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php

```
function apache_request_headers() {
  $arh = array();
  $rx_http = '/\AHTTP_/';
  foreach($_SERVER as $key => $val) {
    if( preg_match($rx_http, $key) ) {
      $arh_key = preg_replace($rx_http, '', $key);
      $rx_matches = array();
      // do some nasty string manipulations to restore the original letter case
      // this should work in most cases
      $rx_matches = explode('_', $arh_key);
      if( count($rx_matches) > 0 and strlen($arh_key) > 2 ) {
        foreach($rx_matches as $ak_key => $ak_val) $rx_matches[$ak_key] = ucfirst($ak_val);
        $arh_key = implode('-', $rx_matches);
      }
      $arh[$arh_key] = $val;
    }
  }
  return( $arh );
}
```